# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on mapView

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

i get this error and EXC_BAD_ACESS when i run my maps application... any idea

```
#0  0x3510741c in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x30a69364 in -[CLLocationManager onClientEventLocation:] ()
#2  0x30a66960 in -[CLLocationManager onClientEvent:supportInfo:] ()
#3  0x30a66b28 in OnClientEvent ()
#4  0x30a5f860 in CLClientInvokeCallback ()
#5  0x30a633e4 in CLClientHandleDaemonData ()
#6  0x357a902c in __CFMessagePortPerform ()
#7  0x3577be46 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#8  0x3577be04 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#9  0x3576e0a4 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#10 0x3576dd7a in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x3576dc88 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x336ace8c in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x318f0f94 in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#14 0x318ee4d4 in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x0000281c in main (argc=1, argv=0x2ffff5e0) at /Users/abcd/Desktop/wataproject/main.m:14
```

Comment: does it happen when you show the map, or after map hides (you go to another view)? and are you showing user location in it?

Comment: post some code or it will be very hard to understand what is wrong with your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://brainwashinc.wordpress.com/2010/01/05/mapkit-crash-getting-user-location/

This helped me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

@vivianaranha's approach might solve the issue but I believe (after encountering this myself) that you are doing something else bad.

Specifically, in my case I had set `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES` so under the hood mapView was wiring itself up to the CLLocationManager. The solution was to ensure that I called `mapView.showsUserLocation = NO` in viewWillDisappear.

Also I discovered that you must have `mapView.userTrackingMode` set to what you require before you make the call to `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`. Putting it all together you end up with something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
    self.mapView.delegate = nil;
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: Seeing a similar problem, but in my case the problem appears to be in setting `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`. I believe I may be setting this property at a "bad time" (such as while the map is animating or doing some other work). Haven't fully narrowed it down, but taking this line out results in it no longer crashing (so far, fingers crossed).